# O que significa "A montanha pariu um rato ?" Onde surgiu?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica, significado-em-contexto

O que significa "A montanha pariu um rato ?" Onde surgiu?
Trabalhar muito e fazer pouco?

Uma montanha que é  algo enorme e um rato um animal tão pequeno

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It originates in [Aesop's fables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop%27s_Fables) and describes actions which promise a lot but deliver a little: something as big as a mountain produced such a little thing as a mouse.

Comment: To add an example -  think about the last season of Game of Thrones. Huge antecipation for a disappointing outcome (to say the least).

Comment: Yes, understand !!